# Numerar las lineas de Un textbox con otro Textbox en tiempo real en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, c#-8.0, textbox

```
public partial class frmCompilador : Form {

    private int lineas; private int aux;
    public frmCompilador()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lineas = 0; aux = 0;
    }
```

Tengo Dos Variables globales guardadas en donde las mando a llamar desde el Evento textChanged de mi textbox **txt_entrada.**[enter image description here][2]

```
 private void txt_Entrada_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblNumeroLineas.Text = (txt_Entrada.GetLineFromCharIndex(txt_Entrada.TextLength) + 1).ToString();

        // Este Codigo Obtiene El Numero de Linea a la hora de un Salto de linea en el Textbox de Entrada
        lineas = txt_Entrada.Lines.Length + 1;
        if(lineas>aux || lineas < aux)
        {
            txtLineas.Clear();
            for (int i= 1; i < lineas; i++)
            {
                txtLineas.Text += "" + i + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            aux = lineas;
        }
    }
```

En este caso si funciona muy bien y numera las lineas  pero el problema que tengo esque cuando el cursor llega al final del limite grafico del textbox no se desplaza automaticamente mi textbox con nombre **txtLineas** conforme a la linea que corresponde

A continuacion una imagen de mi programa:[image: El problema esque no baja automaticamente el scrolldown del textbox con los numeros azules]

Comment: No entendí el problema, puedes explicarlo de otra manera?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [`GetCharIndexFromPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharindexfromposition) para saber qué caracter está siendo dibujado en la esquina y con [`GetLineFromCharIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex) determinar la línea.

Sugiero que como punto uses `0, 4` ya que con `0, 0` detecta la línea anterior en caso de haberse desplazado.

Por cierto, `TextChanged` solo es llamado cuando escribes o borras texto. Por lo que si te desplazas con el cursor o las flechas del teclado no se enterará. Puedes cubrir estos casos actualizando los números de las líneas cada vez que se produzca el evento [`KeyUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keyup) y [`MouseUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup) ya que si usas sus versiones `Down` el evento se produce antes del cambio visual.

Para no repetir código podrías ponerlo en una función así:

```
void ActualizarLineas()
{
    var caracterEnEsquina = txt_Entrada.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, 4));
    var primeraLinea = txt_Entrada.GetLineFromCharIndex(caracterEnEsquina) + 1;
    
    // Aquí va el código donde generas los números de línea
    
}
```